# Can't authenticate Google Cloud with Service Key on GitHub Actions - "unexpected token in JSON at position 0"

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, github-actions

I have the service account key JSON stored as a secret, no errors in the file. Yet every time I run the action it keeps complaining about an unexpected token. What is wrong?

```
Error: google-github-actions/auth failed with: retry function failed after 1 attempt: failed to parse service account key JSON credentials: unexpected token  in JSON at position 0
```

Service Account Key format:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "",
  "private_key_id": "",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "",
  "client_id": "",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": ""
}
```

Workflow:

```
- id: 'auth'
      name: 'Authenticate to Google Cloud'
      uses: 'google-github-actions/auth@v1'
      with:
        credentials_json: $GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS
    - id: 'upload-file'
      name: 'Upload report to Google Cloud'
      uses: 'google-github-actions/upload-cloud-storage@v0'
      with:
        path:  $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/mochawesome-report
        destination: api-test-results
        parent: false
        glob: '*.html'
    - uses: 'google-github-actions/upload-cloud-storage@v0'
      if: always()
      env:
        SLACK_URL: ${{ secrets.SLACK_URL }}
        GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS: ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe a typo in the `auth` step? Just try:

```
- id: 'auth'
      name: 'Authenticate to Google Cloud'
      uses: 'google-github-actions/auth@v1'
      with:
        credentials_json: ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS }}
```

instead of:

```
      with:
        credentials_json: $GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it! Weird that GitHub docs say you can access ```env``` using $.